# Django model of a rent contract using Generic Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to model a rent contract in Django and use the admin form to insert and modify it.
Both owner and tenant can be companies (VAT number) or individuals (no VAT number). Companies and individuals are stored in two different models (Company and Individual).

I'm trying to solve this problem using Generic Foreign Key but I'm not able to show the tenant name in the admin page, only an integer field not friendly at all.

gestimm is the name of the app and that's my oversimplified models:

```
# my gestimm/models.py
#
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models


class Individual(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Contract(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    start = models.DateField()
    stop = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description


class Tenant(models.Model):
    limit = models.Q(app_label='gestimm', model='individual') | models.Q(app_label='gestimm', model='company')
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 null=True, blank=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                     help_text='Tenant', null=True,
                                     limit_choices_to=limit)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    tenant = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

How I tried to solve the problem:

```
# my gestimm/admin.py
#
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Individual, Company, Contract, Tenant


class TenantInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Tenant
    extra = 1


class ContractAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TenantInline]


admin.site.register(Individual)
admin.site.register(Company)
admin.site.register(Contract, ContractAdmin)
```

I found some old discussions but none of the proposed solutions worked.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I installed [django-grappelli](https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

My new admin.py:

```
class TenantInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Tenant
    extra = 1
    related_lookup_fields = {
        'generic': [['content_type', 'object_id']],
    }


class ContractAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        TenantInline,
    ]


admin.site.register(Contract, ContractAdmin)
```

[As intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YU5C.png)